# How do i resolve Async tornado fetching future error

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to use AsyncHTTPClient to Get/Post from a local service that is already running at port 6000.

but i keep getting an error RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x03C9B490>

ps. im using tornado 4.4.2, this error is fixed with the latest version but how do i do it in 4.4.2? Please help!

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import asyncio
import tornado
import urllib
from datetime import datetime
import time

async def client(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = await http_client.fetch(url)
    return response.body

async def main():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    url = "http://localhost:6000/listings"
    result = await client(url)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = asyncio.run(main())
    print(result)
    print(int(time.time() * 1e6))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You <strike>can't use</strike> `asyncio` with Tornado prior to version 5.0.

Use Tornado's own ioloop to run your program:

```
from tornado import ioloop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

---

**UPDATE:** The above solution will work fine, but, if you want, you *can* use asyncio with Tornado 4.x. See: [`tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch4.5/asyncio.html#tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop).